# Multiplication and Binary Conversion at same time

Tags: c

I'm trying to multiply two user inputs using Russian Multiplication and convert that result into Binary at the same time. Keep getting errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
while(1){
int i, choice;
printf("What would you like to do?\n 1. Multiplication \n 2. Exit\n\n");

if(choice == 1){
 int a,b,c;
  a=0;b=0;
  c=0;
  printf("enter your first number\n");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("enter your second number\n");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  while(b>=1){

              a=a*2;
              b=b/2;
              if(b%2==1)
              c=c+a;

              }

              printf("Russian Multiplication result is=%d\n",c);
              getchar();

              {
                  int num, bin;

                  scanf("%d", &num);
                  bin = printbinary(num);
                  printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d\n", num, bin);
              }
              int printbinary(int num);

if (num == 0)

{

    return 0;

}

else

{

    return (num % 2) + 10 * printbinary(num / 2);

}
}
if(choice ==2){
return 0;
}
else{
    printf("That's not an option dude, try again\n");
   }
  }
}
```

Keep getting implicit declaration of function 'printbinary' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                bin == printbinary(num);
Also getting an error that states: 'num' undeclared (first use in this function)   if(num == 0)

Comment: And what do you have so far?

Comment: while(b>=1){
                  a=a*2;
                  b=b/2;
                  if(b%2==1)
                  c=c+a;  
                  }   
                  printf("Russian Multiplication result is=%d\n",c);
                  getchar();
      {
       int num, bin;
      
          scanf("%d", &num);
          bin = printbinary(num);
          printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d\n", num, bin);
      }
      int printbinary(int num);
{
    if ("%d" == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ("%d" % 2) + 10 * printbinary("%d" / 2);

    }

Comment: I have the multiplication down, and a way to convert a value to binary. I just don't know how to combine the two so that the result is whats being converted

Comment: The code you have should be part of the question. Aside from that, though, it's not clear what you're looking for. You have the parts you need...what's keeping you from wiring them up together?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow   Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site. And thats how i put it together, but im getting implicit declaration of function 'printbinary' error. also very new to coding so go easy on me

Comment: @Gio: Your code is not sufficient to reproduce the error, and clearly isn't a complete program. Please provide a [MCVE] (edited into the question). It looks like you failed to actually define `printbinary`, but the code you posted failed to define *main*, so we have no idea what your code might or might not be doing.

Comment: I left some of the code out because when i pasted it, it didn't come out right but i fixed it. There is the complete program

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really are up to, because there are a lot of logical errors in the code. I am going to point out and give alternatives to what caused the errors which you have mentioned in the question.

1. > implicit declaration of function 'printbinary'
   >   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

   This is a result of not defining the function before using or calling it. So declare it globally first as follows before `main()`:

   `#include<stdio.h>
   int printbinary(int);
   int main() {...`

   And what is `int printbinary(int num);` supposed to do after that block of code which 
   so strangely enclosed in `{...}`(I've mentioned this in the next point)? When a function is said to have a return type which isn't `void`, in this case `int`, there should be some int variable or something which is taking it. else it's useless.
2. 

> 'num' undeclared (first use in this function) if(num == 0):

This is because of this code:

```
          {
              int num, bin;
              scanf("%d", &num);
              bin = printbinary(num);
              printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %d\n", num, bin);
          }   //what's the point of these braces buddy??????
```

The variables `num` and `bin` are accessible only inside this block. So when you try to access `num` outside of it (i.e, after the closing bracket(`}`) ), it naturally says it's not not declared.